# The exact distribution of the conditional distribution of the OLS estimator

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, inference, econometrics, asymptotics

This is the problem that I have tried figuring it out for a while, and I still need some advice because there is no explicit derivation in the textbook that I have seen so far. The problem looks easy to me at the first place, but, after pondering, it makes me feel uncertain.

Suppose I have **"the normal regression model"** like this.

$Y_{i}=\beta X_{i}+e_{i}$

Where $X_{i}$ and $Y_{i}$ are scalars and $e_{i}
|Xi  \sim   N(0, σ^2)$. This model makes the assumption
that **the conditional error distribution is exactly normal**.

My question: How can I derive the conditional distribution of the OLS estimator for $β$,
$ \beta^{OLS} |Xi ∼ . . . $ ?

If I have to derive **the exact distribution**, not the approximate one.
That is, I do not need to use asymptotic theory because of the normality assumption imposed on the error distribution.

Any suggestions, please?
I highly appreciate all of your comments.

Kind regards,

AB

Comment: Consider the estimator of $\beta$ as a function of the vector, $Y$, whose multivariate distribution is already specified (up to unknown $\beta$ and $\sigma$.

Comment: Dear @Glen_b  thank you very much.  I think the word 'exact distribution' belied my understanding.  The exact distribution here should be the finite exact sample and one can construct the conditional distribution of $\beta$ as usual with the exact given distribution unlike the asymptotic property that one makes use of the approximation.  Thank you!